# Difficulty Setting AutoFilter Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this type of data:

[image: pic]

I want to setup an AutoFilter to include cells **A1** thru **A4.**  I do not want to include **A5** in the filter range.  This code fails to do that:

```
Sub FilterProblem()
    Range("A1:A4").AutoFilter
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address
End Sub
```

Is it possible to create an AutoFilter on a specific set of rows, regardless of whether the rows below are filled or not?

Comment: As a workaround, I tried inserting a row below bird, filtering, and deleting the row, but on deletion the filter extends to the newly contiguous row.  I suspect the answer is no - that part of the the "auto" in auto-filtering is a frequent check for adjacent cells to include.  Can you use a listobject instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the autofilter, could you define a listobject?

```
Sub FilterProblem()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$A$4"), , xlYes).TableStyle = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Personally I like using ListObjects in VBA - you can iterate over or add rows, reference columns by name, and generally do whatever you want without ever explicitly stating an address range, making the code much easier to read and maintain, and more robust to edits that rearrange columns and rows.